# Any way to hide webpart from dashboard from particular user group?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, permissions, content-query-web-part, filter

I wan give user group permission on list view web part ,and I have sharePoint foundation version

for example: all item of list don't wan a see by user it only show to hr group but user created item wan see by particular user

for that I created different view of list for particular scenario and I add that view in dashboard(home page) but now I hide that web part from the normal user group

Comment: Are you on 2013 or 2010?

Comment: Its 2010 @AsadRefai

Answer (score 1):

under Advanced options in webpart options, you have at the bottom option named Target audience. you can look there and check if that can help you.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention in question, I have share point foundation server which have not target audience feature in them